# GCC's scope depth representation method

Tags: c, scope, declaration

The depth of the description file_scope in GCC is 1, and the external_scope is 0.
I wrote a program to test the results.

```c
int main() {
        int a;
        {
                int b;
        }
        {
                int c;
        }
        if (1) {
                int d;
        }
}
```

The depth of variable `a` is 2, and both `b` and `c` are 3, but the depth of variable `d` is 5.

Why is the depth of variable `d` not 3 or 4?

Comment: What is variable depth and how do you know it?

Comment: In gcc/c/c-decl.c file

Comment: Perhaps because the authors of gcc found it convenient for their purposes. Why not? +1 for the if statement itself, +1 for the then-branch within if, +1 for the braces. This number doesn't have to reflect the number of scopes you unwind in order to get to the top level. It's just an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard (6.8.4 Selection statements)

3 A selection statement is a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of its enclosing block. Each associated substatement is also a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of the selection statement.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    if ( sizeof( struct A { long x; } ) == sizeof( long long ) )
    {
        struct A
        {
            long x;
        } a;

        printf( "sizeof( a ) within if = %zu\n", sizeof( a ) );
    }
    else
    {
        struct A
        {
            long long x;
        } a;
        
        printf( "sizeof( a ) within else = %zu\n", sizeof( a ) );
    }
}
```

Within the if statement there is introduced the type specifier `struct A`

```
    if ( sizeof( struct A { long x; } ) == sizeof( long long ) )
```

In the substatements of the if statement there are also introduced type specifiers with the same name that hide the type specifier introduced in the if statement.

So if to count scopes as you are doing then there are the following scopes;

1. file scope
2. the block scope starting with the parameter list of the
   definition of main
3. the scope of the if statement
4. and the scope of the if statement substatements

gcc can add its own scope for the compound statement of the if statement.

Comment: Since `a` (in the question) is at depth 2, adding two nested scopes should move it to 4, but it's at 5. There's one more scope there somewhere.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the if statement substatements is a block with its own scope, and the compound statement is a block with its own scope too. It may be the same scope but the "depth" variable doesn't have to reflect that accurately. It just needs to take different values for different nested scopes.